# Needed htaccess rewrite to preserve migration to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with this kind of querystring:

http://www.example.com/index.php?action=show&id=4577

I am moving to wordpress with this blog format:

http://www.example.com/archives/4577

But i should preserve wordpress rewrite conditions

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As this is almost certainly _not_ the only pattern you need to use, I'd strongly recommend using the plugin [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) or similar.

Comment: This is not help me find a solution... :/

Comment: Check out the rewrite rules starting at line 90 [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)

Comment: I've already tried that, in any way, but it's like they are bypassed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me (i realized by my own...):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=show&id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule .*$ /archives/%1? [NC,R,L]
```